# Phonegap jsCallback in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cordova

So I understand that we can call a native function by 
cordova.exec(**success**,failure,...

Instead of associating a callback like

```
ChildBrowser._onClose = function()
{
    window.plugins.childBrowser.onClose();
};
```

Instead of doing something like :

```
NSString* jsCallback = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.plugins.childBrowser.onClose('%@');", (NSString*) booleanString];
```

How can I call my **success** callback function when I successfully complete some scenario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try implement this example into your project.

make sure you already define your plugin in your config.xml

```
<feature name="CustomPlugin">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CustomPlugin" />
</feature>
```

Implementing the plug-in by using Objective-C code

CustomPlugin.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>

@interface CustomPlugin : CDVPlugin

- (void)sayHello:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;

@end
```

CustomPlugin.m

```
#import "CustomPlugin.h"

    @implementation CustomPlugin

    - (void)sayHello:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command{

        NSString *responseString =
            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello World, %@", [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0]];

        CDVPluginResult *pluginResult =
            [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:responseString];

        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
    }

    @end
```

Calling a plug-in from JavaScript

```
function initial(){
    var name = $("#NameInput").val();
    cordova.exec(sayHelloSuccess, sayHelloFailure, "CustomPlugin", "sayHello", [name]);
}

function sayHelloSuccess(data){
    alert("OK: " + data);
}

function sayHelloFailure(data){
    alert("FAIL: " + data);
}
```